# APPCMD syntax issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, scripting, appcmd

I am trying to setup recycling logging events, using the following:

```
 appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name=' AppPoolName '].recycling.logEventOnRecycle:time
```

But I am getting this error:

> Failed to process input: The parameter ''].recycling.logEventOnRecycle:time' mus
>   t begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).

I used [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771318%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) but I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell (note the quotes around the second parameter):

```
& appcmd set config /section:applicationPools "/[name='AppPool'].recycling.logEventOnRecycle:Time"
```

or if you want multiple types of events:

```
& appcmd set config /section:applicationPools "/[name='AppPool'].recycling.logEventOnRecycle:PrivateMemory, Time"
```

In cmd.exe, same examples as above:

```
appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='AppPool'].recycling.logEventOnRecycle:Time

appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='AppPool'].recycling.logEventOnRecycle:"PrivateMemory, Time"
```